# Github: Share private repository with another organization

Tags: git, github, repository, mirror

I belong to two github organizations, let's say O1 and O2.

There is one private repository in O1 that can only be accessed by the people who belong to O1.

Is there a way I can share that repository with the people in O2?

I tried `git clone --mirror` but it looks like it's not automatically synced with the original repository

Answer (score 5):

You can share a private repository with specific individuals by following the instructions here:
https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/

Unfortunately, that doesn't let you pull in whole organisations at once.

You could move the repository to another organisation and then add everyone from both O1 and O2 to that org, but that's fairly terrible, as well.

You can *transfer* repositories to other organisations, too:
https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-transfers/

But, again, not quite what you want.

Comment: Chris is right that There is no way you can share the repository with the people in O2 at once (share to other organization), hence you will need to add one by one from other organization.