# Grant a permission to an organization (or all members of it)

Tags: github, organization

Can I grant permission to my repositories to all members of an organization on Github?

I would like to share my repositories with all members of a certain organization. I know that the straightforward way is to update the repositories to the organization's account. But then, the owner of the repositories looks the organization, and the management is a bit confusing. I would like to keep them as my own and make the responsibility clear. Also, my repositories are private and should be hidden from the public.

So, I would like to grant permission to the organization or all members of it.

Comment: Sorry, an important information is lost. My repositories are private and should be hidden from public.

Comment: Does this answer your question? (the answer appears to be no) [Github: Share private repository with another organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818482/github-share-private-repository-with-another-organization)

Comment: Thank you very much. That is what I wanted to know, sadly.